# How to run ansible command on a single server during deployment to many servers?

Tags: symfony, ansible, devops, doctrine-migrations

I'm using Ansistrano to deploy my Symfony2 application. Application uses Doctrine, oso I'm also using DoctrineMigrationsBundle. Now, my problem is that I would like to run database migration at the end of deployment process, but I want this operation to be called only once, and I know that ansible by default run all commands from playbook on all given servers. Is there any way to tell ansible to run a specific command on a single server from a set of all servers to which I deploy my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [run_once](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) for this.

Example from the docs:

```
---
# ...

  tasks:

    # ...

    - command: /opt/application/upgrade_db.py
      run_once: true

    # ...
```